AppImages won't run on 24.04
Regardless of what AppImage it is, attempting to run it produces a result similar to this:
[192808:0821/033305.658883:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(158)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /tmp/.mount_balenamyajdO/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
/tmp/.mount_balenamyajdO/balena-etcher: line 10: 192808 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "${script_dir}"/balena-etcher.bin "$@"
Zero exceptions found.  I am running XUbuntu 24.04 on a Ryzen 5 3600.  Everything worked perfectly until I "upgraded" from XUbuntu 22.04.

Your issue maybe related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/2046844 (search for appimage) as the location where they are stored tends to vary & thus fix was somewhat problematic..  see esp. comment #36 onwards...   Please note I don't use appimages and thus haven't taken much notice of issues, but this is where I'd probably look first for appimage/sandbox issues...  (you should find the workaround to test if this is the issue anyway)

This question is similar to: How to permanently disable Ubuntu's new AppArmor user namespace creation restrictions?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you do not mind relaxing your security settings, then this fix works for me, which --no-sandbox, --disable-setuid-sandbox, and changing the permissions on /tmp all do not.
sudo sysctl -w kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns=0

Snag: you need to redo this every time you boot.

No. You don't need to do anything every time you boot. Please see the linked answer in the comments above

@ArchismanPanigrahi I think you do not understand what I am saying here. Your "correction" is wrong. It is perfectly possible to set this command to be executed every time, but that is a bad solution and a security risk and nobody should do it.

The command you asked to run creates the same security risks. Also, running something without sandbox is also a security risk. TBH, doing anything in a computer can cause a security risk.... This is my opinion, but Ubuntu's decision to blindly not letting software run does not actually increase any security.

Once the SUID bug is fixed this should be removed.  I would NOT recommend this as a long-term answer/solution - only until the bug is fixed.

Exactly. @ThomasWard is correct: the point here being that while the command I offer does reduce security, yes, it is only temporary and has no lasting effect. The next reboot undoes it, and then if or when Canonical fixes this, users will simply not need to enter the command and can forget it ever happened. Which negates Archisman Panigrahi's objection.

@ArchismanPanigrahi as written, this command will need to run every reboot.  If someone follows the process of adding this to /etc/sysctl.conf specifically or such then it will persist, but in both cases even if they do that they should undo this once the bug is fixed.

@LiamProven you've misread my statement, my statement does NOT indicate whether or not it needs executed on every boot or not.  I did not state anything about if it needs reapplied at boot or such because I don't know if it does.  The bug that is linked has a 'single-reboot-needed' solution of adding this to either /etc/sysctl.conf or to /etc/sysctl.d/60-apparmor-namespace.conf but I don't specifically state if it needs to be reexecuted on boot or not.  My statement covers the global issue of "this is insecure so make sure you undo it after the bug is fixed" regardlelss.
